# Two consecutive numbers are removed from the progression 1, 2, 3..n. The arithmetic mean of the remaining numbers is 105/4. What is the value of n?

Tags: sequences-and-series, modular-arithmetic

Two consecutive numbers are removed from the progression 1, 2, 3..n. The arithmetic mean of the remaining numbers is 105/4. What is the smallest value of n?
?What are the two numbers removed?

Now many answers are given but they are given in a hit and trial method.
Is there any other method to solve this problem?

Comment: Is the mean of the remaining numbers 261/4 or 105/4?

Comment: Let $k$ denote the smaller of the two numbers removed then you know $k+1\le n$ and you can write an equation in $n$ and $k$ with whichever of the two fractions you decide is correct on the right hand side. You should make at least that much of an effort before asking for help.

Comment: are you sure that we have enough information ?

Comment: At the moment there is just ONE answer (mine) and it is fully algebraic. You did nothing to try and solve the problem and now you say that my answer is "hit and trial"? Come on! :)

Comment: yes....it came in our school ecam...@datodatuashvili

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\sum _{k=1}^n k= \dfrac{1}{2} n (n+1)$

Subtract $x+(x+1)$. The sum is then $\dfrac{1}{2} n (n+1) -2x-1$

The mean is then $\dfrac{\frac{1}{2} n (n+1) -2x-1}{n-2}=\dfrac{105}{4}$

$x=\dfrac{1}{8} \left(2 n^2-103 n+206\right)$ and $0<x<n$

$x>0 \to 2 n^2-103 n+206>0$ which means $n\ge 50$

And $x<n \to \dfrac{1}{8} \left(2 n^2-103 n+206\right)<n $ which means $2\le n\le 53$

so we have $50\le n\le 53$ but the only value that gives an integer $x$ is $n=50$

Finally the solution is $x=7$ when $n=50$

Comment: I suspect that since the OP could not even obtain the equation in $x$ in $n$ that they will not understand how you obtained the solution to the equation.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales Do you think that now it can be more understandable?

Comment: Yes, I think so. Thanks.

Comment: +1 nice job. N is even so 51 and 53 are excluded but any logical reason for 50 and not 52 ?

Comment: @Isham $52$ gives $x=\dfrac{159}{4}$ while $x$ must be integer

Answer (score 0):

Since the given arithmetic mean in the title is $261/4$, we know that $(n-2)\times 261/4$ must be an integer, so $n\equiv 2 \bmod 4$.

The sum of the full set of integers from $1$ to $n$ is $n(n+1)/2$, with average $\color{blue}{(n+1)/2}$. Removing two numbers from that set cannot change the average by more than $1$, since removing the largest two makes it $(n-1)/2 = \color{blue}{(n+1)/2}-1$ and removing the two smallest makes it $(n-1)/2 + 2= \color{blue}{(n+1)/2}+1$.

So we know that $261/4 -1 \le \color{blue}{(n+1)/2} \le 261/4+1$ so $128.5\le n\le 132.5$. Now since only $130\equiv 2 \bmod 4$ in this range, we can be confident that  $n=130$ (assuming a well-posed question).